# MVC controller changes input field after submission

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js

I have an amount field in my Form that I multiply by 100 after submission in my controller.
The problem is that the view renders the multiplication before moving on to the next page.
How can I avoid that?
More generally, how do I prevent the view to display the modified value once it's submitted?

I'm using ember.js with rails in the backend, but I think it's more of a MVC problem.

this is the view:

```
{{input value=model.amount mask="999[999].99"
        classNames="form-control" placeholder=(t 'transactions.amount')}}
```

and this is the controller:

```
  actions: {
create: function() {
  var _this = this;
  var model = this.get('model');

  model.set('amount', model.get('amount') * 100);

  model.save().then(function(transaction) {
    _this.get('target').transitionToRoute(_this.get('destination'), transaction.get('id'));
  }, function(response){
    _this.set('errors', response.errors);
  });
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide your codes please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a good case to use a computed property, which you would use in your template:

```
displayAmount: function(key, value, previousValue) {
    // setter
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      this.set('amount', value * 100);
    }

    // getter
    return this.get('amount') / 100;
  }.property('amount')
```

The syntax for computed properties is going to change soon so you may need this version:

```
displayAmount: Ember.computed("amount", {
  get: function() {
    return this.get("amount") / 100;
  },
  set: function(key, amount) {
   this.set("amount", amount * 100);
  }
})
```